# .NET and COM Interoperability : release COM from .NET client

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

Assume I have a COM object (unmanaged) and .NET Client.

Is it necessary to call from the .NET client `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` method in order to release the COM object?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no need to explicitly release a COM object from a .Net client.  The COM object will be collected like any other .Net object and will release it's underlying native handle once all references to it are removed.

Explicit use of `FinalReleaseComObject` can actually lead to programming errors.  If another component in your code is still referencing the COM object you will be yanking out the native object out from under it.  That will possibly lead to runtime failures down the road.

Comment: While "in theory" there may be no need, "in practice", there *definitely is*. Also, don't use FinalReleaseComObject, but rather ReleaseComObject for *each time any* COM object has been brought over the COM-.NET boundary. I do Outlook Addin programming: and I can say, giving objects *explicit lifetimes is the only way to create a working add-in*. Period. (I use a helper/wrapper class that supports Dispose I use with `using`.)

Comment: Wrong practice.  You GC.Collect() + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() if you have to, never gets it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't work with the Outlook Object Model. Various related "solutions" involve trying to invoke that sequence *twice* in a row. It just does not work "in practice" (in the cases I deal with).

Comment: @pst if `GC.Collect + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` doesn't work but `FinalReleaseComObject` does then your `FinalReleaseComObject` is in all likelyhood orphaning a managed reference to the COM object somewhere in your program.

Comment: There's only one kind of COM, it isn't different for Outlook.  Maybe you ought to ask a question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Been there, done that for many months. The way you have described is *just not reliable*. It has to do with the GC pass not (necessarily) picking up the RCWs as needing to be reclaimed, IIRC. It really is no different than `using` vs. hoping the Stream finalizer will run. Sometimes it just *doesn't run when it should*. Coupled with caching (notorious in the OOM), this just "makes things not work".

Answer (score 2):

A *modified* "Yes", and a "No".

First off, bear in mind that `ReleaseComObject` *does not* automatically decrease the real COM object ref-count. Rather it decreases the internal RCW counter. (Every time the *same* COM object is moved from COM->NET it will use the *same* RCW and increment the RCW counter by one.) Likewise, `FinalRelaseComObject` also affects the RCW counterand effectively "sets it to 0". It is when the RCW counter goes to zero that .NET will decrease the *actual* COM ref-count.

So, **"yes", *but modified for these rules***:

1. *Every time* an object cross from COM->NET it *should* have `ReleaseComObject`, *but not* `FinalReleaseComObject`, invoked upon it. That is, it should be invoked *once* for each time the object crosses, *even if it results in a reference-equals RCW*.
2. The number of references to the RCW (which is just a proxy wrapper) do not matter; only the times the object has crossed the boundary. See rule #1. (It is important to control references and who keeps them, but the "worst" that happens in this case is an exception from using a "detached RCW" which is *no different* than using a Disposed stream.)

I say the rules above and *not* `FinalReleaseComObject` because the RCW objects are cached in an identity proxy, so **using `FinalReleaseComObject` *will affect COM->NET boundary crossings you didn't even know about***! (This is bad and, on this point, I entirely agree with JaredPars answer.)

And **"no" in that, *when an RCW is reclaimed* (the finalizer is called), it will automatically "release" the COM reference** (effectively call `FinalReleaseComObject` on itself). Remember that since there is only one RCW object this means that it will *never* be reclaimed as long as there is a reference to it in .NET. If the RCW is reclaimed there is *no problem* because, from above, there are no more references to said RCW and thus .NET knows it can decrease the COM ref-count by one (which may cause the COM object to be destroyed).

However, since the .NET GC is finicky and *non-deterministic*, relying on this behavior means that object-lifetimes are not controlled. This can cause *many* subtle issues when working with the Outlook Object Model, for instance. (It may be less prone to issues with other COM servers, but the OOM does funny "caching" of objects internally. It is easy to get a "Item has already been modified" exception when not controlling lifetimes explicitly.)

In my code I have a `ComWrapper` class that supports `IDisposable`. This allows me to pass around RCW objects obtained from the COM->NET with *clear lifetime ownership*. I have had very few issues (almost none, actually) in my Outlook-Addin development after switching to this approach and *numerous* issues before hand. The "downside" is that COM->NET boundary needs to be determined, but once that is, then internally all the lifetimes are correctly handled.

Happy coding.