# Excel process still runs in background

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm reading some data from a sheet of an excel file using interop library. I get the data just fine by using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and then reading all data in the sheet.

```
Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Workbook excelWorkbook = ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open(excelFileNamePath);
_Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[excelSheetName];
Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
//...for loops for reading data
ExcelApp.Quit();
```

But after my application terminates, I tried to edit my excel file and had some problems while opening. Apparently the excel process keeps on running in the background even though I called `ExcelApp.Quit()`. Is there a way to properly close the excel file that the application uses? I'm new to c# so i'm probably missing something here.

Edit: Solved! Apparently there's a [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/2987535) for com objects that discourages using 2 dots.

```
Excel.Application ExcelApp2 = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks excelWorkbooks = ExcelApp2.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelWorkbooks.Open(excelFileName);
Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[excelSheetName];
//...
excelWorkbook.Close();       
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelRange);
ExcelApp2.Quit();
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962157/safely-disposing-excel-interop-objects-in-c

Comment: Have you tried this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q317109

Comment: @CJBS They didn't find an answer either! But I will try to implement one of the suggestions there. thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was another similar question - and answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570/3063884), in which the solution was to avoid using double-dot notation. Instead, define variables for each object used along the way, and individually use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on each one.

Copying straight from the linked solution:

```
var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(/*params*/)
```

---> instead use -->

```
var workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
var workbook = workbooks.Open(/*params*/)
```

Then, when done, release each COM object:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```

Comment: I just found the same question and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Long time no answer but what worked for me was to call the GC.Collect(); from the caller,

i.e. instead of

```
main()
{
    ...
    doexcelstuff();
    ...
}

void doexcelstuff()
{
    Excel.Application ExApp2 = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelWb = ExApp2 .Workbooks.Open(excelFName);
    Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWb.Sheets[excelSName];
    //...
    excelWb.Close();
    ExApp2.Quit();     
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWb);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExApp2);
    excelWb = null;
    excelWorksheet= null;
    ExApp2= null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Using above Excel does not die

**but a very small change, to where the GC is called from**

```
main()
{
    ...
    doexcelstuff();
    GC.Collect();      // <<-- moved the GC to here (the caller)
    ...
}

void doexcelstuff()
{
    Excel.Application ExApp2 = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelWb = ExApp2 .Workbooks.Open(excelFName);
    Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWb.Sheets[excelSName];
    //...
    excelWb.Close();
    ExApp2.Quit();     
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWb);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExApp2);
    excelWb = null;
    excelWorksheet= null;
    ExApp2= null;
    // removed the GC from here
}
```

My guess is the garbage collector needs to also quietly clean up internally created temp values (including refs/pointers) from the heap - some of which I guess in this case are pointing to COM objects.

(Just takes a smidgen of understanding of how machines work underneath the source code.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your workbook. Close it and then release it before quitting the Excel application:

```
excelWorkbook.close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
ExcelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: The error still pops up. It says "The document with the name ... is already open"

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked!

```
//Initializing
Application excelApp = new Application();
Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(pathExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", 
                               true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, 
                               true, 1, 0);
Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

//closing
excelWorksheet = null;

excelWorkbook.Close();
excelWorkbook = null;

excelApp.Quit();
excelApp = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interop is notoriously buggy... I use the following method after saving my workbook, and no longer have issues with Excel remaining open when I exit my applications:

```
while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb) > 0);
while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl) > 0);

wb = null;
xl = null;

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

wb is my workbook object, and xl is my Excel.Application object.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I can see how buggy it is now, this is so annoying!

Comment: Are you saving and closing your stuff before you call the code above?

I do this:

wb.SaveAs(
 _saveFile,
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
 Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,
 false,
 false,
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
 Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing
);

wb.Saved = true;

Comment: FWIW, the `FinalReleaseComObject` method releases the managed reference to a COM object. Calling this method is equivalent to calling the `ReleaseComObject` method in a loop until it returns 0 (zero), as you've done above. And in my case, I didn't need to set the objects to null before calling `GC.Collect()`. I also don't see a need to call that method twice and the call to `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` should occur _after_ the call to `GC.Collect()`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked :
//opening

```
        var excelFile = new Application();
        Workbook workBook1 = excelFile.Workbooks.Open(goldenCopy_path);
        Workbook workBook2 = excelFile.Workbooks.Open(new_path);

        Worksheet goldWorkSheet, newWorkSheet;
        goldWorkSheet = workBook1.Worksheets[1];
        newWorkSheet = workBook2.Worksheets[1];
```

//closing
//it will release the workbook from visual studio

```
        goldWorkSheet = null;
        newWorkSheet = null;

        workBook1.Close();
        workBook2.Close();
        workBook1 = null;
        workBook2 = null;

        excelFile.Quit();
        excelFile = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked on me.

```
        Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        Excel.Workbooks excelWorkbooks = null;
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
        Excel.Range range = null;

        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelWorkbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        excelWorkbook = excelWorkbooks.Open(excelName);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

        range = xlWorkSheet.Range["C3"] ;
        range.Value = "Update Data";
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(path);
            
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        excelWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
        excelWorkbooks.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbooks);
        excelApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
var Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel").Select(x => x.Id.ToString());
Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Workbook excelWorkbook = ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open(excelFileNamePath);
_Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[excelSheetName];
Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
//...for loops for reading data
foreach (Process pros in Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"))
{
    if (!array1.Contains(pros.Id.ToString()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pros.Id.ToString());
        pros.Kill();

    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).