# Edit an existing Excel file in c#. COMException

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

So, I have created an Excel file in my same wpf Application on the Main Window. 
Now, I want to edit that file so that I can add another worksheet and place some data on it.

The file creates itself just fine and puts all the necessary data on it, but when I try to call it again a COMExcpetion comes up saying that it can't found the file, but the file IS there !!

I think it is nothing mayor, but thank you so much for any help !

Here is the code:

```
private void Nextday_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        xlApp.Visible = true;

        Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:Users\Public\Documents\Report.xls");
        Worksheet ws2 = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[2];
        ws2.Name = "Part Function";

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        int i = 1;
        ws2.Cells[i, 1] = "Part Function Auto";
        i++;
        ws2.Cells[i, 1] = "Problem Reported in TestID#:";
        i++;
        ws2.Cells[i, 1] = "Problem is:";
        i++;

        ws2.Cells[2, 2] = testBox.Text;

        wb.Save();
        wb.Close();
      }
```

And here is how I created the Excel file in the first place.

```
 private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        xlApp.Visible = false;

        Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        ws.Name = "Personal Info";
        wb.Sheets.Add(After: wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count]);


        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        TextRange programTxt = new TextRange(program.Document.ContentStart, program.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange dateTxt = new TextRange(date.Document.ContentStart, date.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange vinTxt = new TextRange(vin.Document.ContentStart, vin.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange dandrTxt = new TextRange(dandr.Document.ContentStart, dandr.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange cdsidTxt = new TextRange(cdsid.Document.ContentStart, cdsid.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange milestoneTxt = new TextRange(milestone.Document.ContentStart, milestone.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange alertTxt = new TextRange(alert.Document.ContentStart, alert.Document.ContentEnd);

        int i = 1;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "Program:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "Date:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "VIN:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "D & R:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "CDS ID:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "Milestone:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "Alert:";
        i++;
        ws.Cells[i, 1] = "Region:";
        i++;
        int j = 1;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = programTxt.Text;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = dateTxt.Text;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = vinTxt.Text;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = dandrTxt.Text;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = cdsidTxt.Text;
        j++; 
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = milestoneTxt.Text;
        j++;
        ws.Cells[j, 2] = alertTxt.Text;
        j++;

        if (EU.IsChecked == true)
        {
            ws.Cells[j, 2] = EU.Content;
            j++;
        }
        if (Canada.IsChecked == true)
        {
            ws.Cells[j, 2] = Canada.Content;
            j++;
        }
        if (USA.IsChecked == true)
        {
            ws.Cells[j, 2] = USA.Content;
            j++;
        }

        wb.SaveAs(@"C:Users\Public\Documents\Report.xls");
        wb.Close();
      }
```

EDIT, FIXED

So, we fixed it! 
I don't really know why but apparently the file path was the problem. I changed it to `WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Report.xls");`
and now it works !

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have the file locked. You need to close your Workbook and Application.

```
wb.Close(); 
ws.Close(); 
xlapp.Quit();
```

Comment: I did it  and it still not working, same error as before. Thank you though ! I should have closed the application too.

Comment: Does this help [Releasing COM Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27930662/2621185)

Comment: Yes, a lot ! Thank you :)