# "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"?

Tags: c#

I am doing unit testing.

I have 2 projects in my solution 1 is library project and 1 is test project.
Library project has some com components. and test project is testing functions in the library project. and these library functions are using these com objects.

1st unit test execute successfully but when i try to excute 2 unit tests sequentially then in the 2nd unit test i am getting the error "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" when i try to access these com objects.

Answer (score 1):

This means someone is using [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) incorrectly or, worse yet, using [`Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx). The 1st unit test is affecting the 2nd through this associated side-effect, perhaps in a tear-down method. The first step to solving this is to find out exactly *which* object/access/location is causing that exception.

This happens because a method is invoked upon an RCW for which the COM object has already been released (COM ref-count set to 0) which means `ReleaseComObject` has been called too many times or `FinalReleaseComObject` has been called at all.

If you *own* a RCW object (have "brought it into the CLR"), and it's lifetime is up, `ReleaseComObject` is okay (set the variable to `null` as well to avoid using it again). Using `FinalReleaseComObject` is usually *never okay* because it's impossible to correctly keep track of lifetimes with it. The trick is to remember that *a single RCW object* represents *one or more* times that a COM object has been "brought into the CLR" and has an internal (non-COM) counter.

In *many cases* the GC will correctly handled RCW cleanup when their finalizer is run. And at the time the RCW is not strongly reachable so that exception *cannot* be generated. Using an explicit `ReleaseComObject` is [only] required/useful in times when *strict control* of the COM lifetime is required (think of a "shared" `Dispose` for COM objects). This comes up a good bit when dealing with Add-In development for Microsoft Office products :)

There are additional details (at my answer) in [.NET and COM Interoperability : release COM from .NET client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709141/net-and-com-interoperability-release-com-from-net-client/9709506#9709506) and a counter-article [ReleaseComObject considered dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx)

Happy coding.

Comment: Can u tell me how to explicitely ReleaseComObject. and where i should i call dispose. i don't have knowloadge about Idisposable interface.

Comment: You *don't* call `Dispose`. And `ReleaseComObject` should only be used when needed. I was just explaining what causes this exception. My linked response has more details on how RCWs work and when `ReleaseComObject` should be used and what side-effects and issues it has. Again, this exception is caused when code incorrectly uses `ReleaseComObject` or `FinalReleaseComObject`: a RCW object (which is a .NET object) is still floating about *even though the underlying COM object is freed (ref-count is 0)*.